# Spring Security java configuration and login form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, apache-tiles

I've read about spring security also seen some examples but I can't make it work... I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Please I'll appreciate some explication because I'm getting hard time to understand this.

Using Spring mvc 4.3.3, Spring Security 4.2.0, Tiles 3, CSS, Java 1.7, Eclipse neon.

1.- My first page is login page (I don't use a home page or index).

2.- I want Spring Security take user and pass from my login (first page shown in browser), also I'm using `<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">` in my login but something is wrong.

[image]

3.- I want it to redirect to the same view to all users /myPanel (I'll change menus acording to user role)

Structure;

[image]

Classes (removed imports and packages); UPDATE:

ApplicationContextConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("mx.com.myapp.*")
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();

        // TilesView 3
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "tilesConfigurer")
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();

        // TilesView 3
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tiles.xml");

        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
```

WebMvcConfig.java:

```
    @Configuration
//@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

//  @Override
//  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
//
//      // Default..
//  }
//
//  @Override
//  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//      configurer.enable();
//  }
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

SpringWebAppInitializer.java

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // UtF8 Charactor Filter.
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);

        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }

}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                   .withUser("mkyong").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
        System.out.println("SpringSecurity ConfigureGlobal");
    }

    //  .csrf() is optional, enabled by default, if using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter constructor
//  @Override
//  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//
//      System.out.println("SpringSecurity configure");
//        http.authorizeRequests()
//        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
//        .antMatchers("/myPanel**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
//        .and().formLogin()
//              .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
//              .permitAll()
//        .and()
//            .csrf();
//  }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll().and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/path/**");
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/" })
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        return "loginPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/myPanel" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView myPanel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("INICIA REQUEST");

        System.out.println("-------- " + request.getParameter("user"));


        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** This is protected page!</h3> **********</div><br><br>";

        System.out.println("TERMINA REQUEST");
        return new ModelAndView("homePage", "message", message);
    }

  //Spring Security see this :
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        System.out.println("/login SpringSecurity");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("homePage");

        return model;
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="<c:url value='/login' />" method="post">

                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error">${error}</div>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                    <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                </c:if>

                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" class="input-txt" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" /> 
                <div class="login-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <strong><a href="#" class="lnk">I've forgotten something</a>  | 
                    <a href="#" class="lnk">Register</a></strong>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--right">Sign in</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you need formlogin to point to /login, but ramp logging up on spring security and it will tell you where its looking for login.html.

Comment: But if I do that it will re-send me to the login right? after all my login is my first page. :confused:

Answer (score 0):

Your missing permit all on the login page -

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("SpringSecurity configure");
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/myPanel**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .and().formLogin()
          .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
          .permitAll()
    .and()
        .csrf();
}
```

Comment: Hey farrellmr, still getting 404 :s

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your setup is quite *over-complicated*, try to simplify it.

Spring security config:

```
 @Configuration
    public static class WebFormSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll().and()
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }
    }
```

Ignore public resources

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/path/**");
    }
```

And MVC config, you don't have to have implementation of `/login` action:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

Comment: For a moment I tought it worked but no... oh my kokoro... could be something wrong with my jsp?

<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">